# matplotlib aggregate multiple points of a series within a pixel

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a pandas series ts with index in datetime and its resolution is 1s; this time series spans 23 hours. I am trying to plot this on multiple charts with a config parameter chart_sec (how many secs showing up in one chart) with a fixed dpi=20; the resolution may not be enough to plot every single point of ts in the chart.

```
import pyplot as plt
ax = plt.subplot()
dates = [dt.to_datetime() for dt in ts.index]
ax.plot_date(dates, ts, fmt='k-', color='grey')
plt.savefig(fname, dpi=20)
```

Question 1, I don't know which value I m plotting using the above code (is it the value of the first or last point in a pixel?) 
Question 2, if I want to sum values of points within one pixel, how to do it?

Comment: Hi, I'm not exactly sure what you mean here by having "multiple points in one pixel".  You should just get a chart with 7200 points - depending on the zoom you might or might not be able to resolve this clearly.  Have you got a sample `ts` and a sample output that you can post?

Comment: If you're trying to save a figure and be able to distinguish each point, one trick is to use a large figure size (e.g. `plt.figure(figsize=(70,70))`) and save as a vector typr (pdf) or high dpi.  If you're viewing in the standard matplotlib window, you can zoom in.

Comment: @JRichardSnape thanks for replying. I have edited the question; the savefig has a fixed dpi that may not be enough to plot every point of ts in a chart. Hope this can clarify my questions.

Comment: no problem for replying.  When you say "the savefig has a fixed dpi", do you mean that in your application you can't change the dpi from 20?  There's nothing in the matplotlib library that stops you using very high (I think arbitrarily high) dpi.  Can you change the figsize, or not?  If you can't change either figsize or dpi, I do see the problem.

Comment: I thought dpi will determine the fig size originally; not very familiar with matplotlib. The figure size is fixed but I can change the dpi. How can I set the dpi correctly for displaying charts?

Comment: When you say "displaying", do you mean on screen, or for saving?  (The answer differs...)

Comment: Anyway - for saving, you can just say (e.g.) `plt.savefig(fname, dpi=1200)`.  If you want to control figure size, you probably want to control the creation of the figure more explicitly, rather than using `plt.subplot()`

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea if you need to distinguish the points is to save the figure at large size and high dpi. I'm guessing a bit what your data looks like from your example.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ts = pd.DataFrame(50*pd.np.random.rand(7200)+pd.np.array(range(7200)),
                  index=pd.DatetimeIndex(freq='s',start='01-01-2016',periods=7200))

plt.figure(figsize=(35,35))
# will be a <matplotlib.figure.Figure object>
dates = [dt.to_datetime() for dt in ts.index]
plt.plot_date(dates, ts, fmt='k-', ms=0, color='grey')
# will be a [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object>]
plt.savefig('hires.png', dpi=600)
```

This produces a nearly 3MB png file, which looks like a slightly noisy straight line when viewed zoomed out, but when you zoom to 100% you can see the individual points as shown below:

[image: Small portion of line graph zoomed to 100%]

Still not brilliantly well distinguished, but you can play with the picture size vs. dpi to suit your individual requirements.

N.B. If you need to view in the normal matplotlib figure window (rather than save), you can zoom in. You can also save the zoomed in view, which saves exactly what you see on the screen.